# how can I override a css setting set for all selectors

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The Bootstrap css file has an `@media print` section which sets the following css rule:

```
* {
    color: #000 !important;
    text-shadow: none !important;
    background: transparent !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
  }
```

I would like to override the background property to be able to print different kinds of backgrounds in my app.

I need to override to preserve backward compatibility of my bootstrap files of course.

I don't find the way to do it.

Can you help? 
Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `!important` clausule from background.

So change it to:

```
* {
    color: #000 !important;
    text-shadow: none !important;
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: none !important;
  }
```

Then add style for body

```
body {
    background: red;
}
```

EDIT:

if you dont't want to remove !important from bootstrap, just add !important to you body background - that dhouls override it:

```
body {
   background: red !important;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to modify the Bootstrap files because otherwise, I won't be able to upgrade them anymore. I need to override them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This solves the problem of the body's background but not of the backgrounds of all other elements.

Comment: for any other elements you need to style them specifically as well

Comment: It's what I was afraid off. There is no way to do it then... thanks.